# 3G Data Usage utility for a netbook?

Tags: netbook, bluetooth, 3g

I infrequently browse on my netbook via my 3G cell/mobile phone.

The data becomes EXORBITANTLY expensive once I've gone over my cap.  AND the telco's online usage meter can be up to 2 days out of date.  I'm a bit fearful of windows update yanking down a service pack or something like that.

Can someone recommend a little utility that can monitor my data usage?  Just something simple, low on resources, for Windows XP.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: win xp, updated the question..

Answer (score 1):

A long time ago I used to use a utility called [netlimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/) to throttle the amount of bandwidth any given application would use.  They make a free version which you can download on [this page](http://www.netlimiter.com/download.php) which will give you all the information you need to track how much bandwidth you are using on your computer.

[image]